# Why is my attribute selector working when it doesn't have any whitespace in it?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) the following about the `[attr~=value]` attribute selector:

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is a
>   whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly value.

If `liquid` is not separated by whitespace, then why is it working?

```css
[data-vegetable~="liquid"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Ingredients for my recipe: <i lang="fr-FR">Poulet basquaise</i>
<ul>
  <li data-quantity="1kg" data-vegetable>Tomatoes</li>
  <li data-quantity="3" data-vegetable>Onions</li>
  <li data-quantity="3" data-vegetable>Garlic</li>
  <li data-quantity="700g" data-vegetable="not spicy like chili">Red pepper</li>
  <li data-quantity="2kg" data-meat>Chicken</li>
  <li data-quantity="optional 150g" data-meat>Bacon bits</li>
  <li data-quantity="optional 10ml" data-vegetable="liquid">Olive oil</li>
  <li data-quantity="25cl" data-vegetable="liquid">White wine</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `one of which is exactly value` You only have one, so of course there is no space separation, it's saying to use multiple, space is the delimiter

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about programming, more about a misinterpretation of the copy describing this particular functionality

Comment: Just try this on a javascript console: `"liquid".split(' ')`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney in this case half of SO questions need to be closed ... missunderstanding or missintreprating the spec is a programming question because you cannot correctly write your program if you don't correctly understand the description which is not always trivial.

Comment: Not sure it's close-worthy, but it's certainly downvote-worthy, IMO, as this is purely a failure to read the plain description of a selector on a tutorial website (*which includes examples*) correctly.

Comment: @TylerH I'd oppose to that. The asker clearly has read the documentation. He even posted the relevant text which is a good thing. And the documentation is not that elegantly written, that anyone can understand it immediately. I myself know the `[x~=y]` selector very well and after I read the doc, I wasn't so sure about that. I had to try it out to assure myself that my understanding of the selector is right and the understanding of the doc is not.

Comment: @yunzen If read in isolation, perhaps, but if read with all the other examples, it should be quite clear (or one would have the same question about every other `attr` selector). Not getting it here only is tantamount to a brain fart, at best, IMO.

Comment: @TylerH There is only one example regarding `[x~=y]` and that doesn't show the whitespace separated list aspect, as this list would go in the HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *separated by whitespace* but:

> a whitespace-separated list of words

Which mean a list of words where you have whitespace between and if alone no need whitespace because there is nothing to separate.

```css
[data-vegetable~="liquid"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid other and other">this one</li>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid">and this one</li>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid   ">also this one</li>  
  <li data-vegetable="another liquid   ">also this one</li>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid-one">NOT this one !!</li>
  <li data-vegetable="another-liquid">NOT this one !!</li>
  <li data-vegetable="aliquid">NOT this one !!</li>
</ul>
```

For the last ones you will need `*`

```css
[data-vegetable*="liquid"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid other and other">this one</li>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid">and this one</li>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid   ">also this one</li>  
  <li data-vegetable="another liquid   ">also this one</li>
  <li data-vegetable="liquid-one">this one too!!</li>
  <li data-vegetable="another-liquid">this one too!!</li>
  <li data-vegetable="aliquid">this one too!!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this example clears it up. Played around with it using `=` and `~=` to see the difference.

Comment: @Temani In your last example you actually need `[data-vegetable*=" liquid"],
[data-vegetable^="liquid"] {
  color: red;
}`

Comment: @yunzen why? my intention was to select if the word `liquid` exist whataver the case is.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have the text `NOT this one !!` in the last to `<li>`s

Comment: @yunzen should copy/past be blamed ? :)

Answer (score 0):

A list of words has separators between the words.
If the list contains only one word, there are no separators

Answer (score 0):

What that means is, the attribute (`data-vegetable` in this case) can have multiple values, assigned to it in one string using whitespace to delimit the values, like `data-vegetable="liquid foo bar"`, which gives `data-vegetable` three values 'liquid', 'foo' and 'bar'.

The selector can be used to match any of these values, so you will get this element when matching either `[data-vegetable~="liquid"]`, `[data-vegetable~="foo"]` or `[data-vegetable~="bar"]`.

Answer (score 0):

It said: "whitespace-separated list of words"

That means that it is a list, separated by whitespace. But a list can have only one item. So in that case, no spaces are needed.